# I want to add echo a JS variable in my button's value field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i want to `echo` the value of capnum in my `button's` `value` `field`...how do i go with it?
MY code goes here -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var capnum = 0;
function add()
{
 capnum++;
 document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = capnum;
}
</script>

<button name="subject" type="submit" value="<script> document.write(capnum) </script>" onclick="showUser(this.value);add()" >NEXT</button>
```

Comment: Please provide full javascript code.

Comment: What's showUser function.

Comment: where is id in your button?
give button id

Comment: not needed at the moment bro @kc1994

Comment: Please explain more about what exactly you want with this

Comment: i tried getelementbyid.value but the output is buggy

Comment: done guys.....thanks alott...it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add id="display" to your button.
I also changed .innerHTML to .value since your post says you want to change its value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var capnum = 0;

    function add()
    {
     capnum++;
     document.getElementById('display').value = capnum;
    }

    function showUser(i) { // i just added this to test if value was changing
        alert(i);
    }
</script>

<button id="display" name="subject" type="submit" value="" onclick="add(); showUser(this.value);" >NEXT</button>
```

I also moved showUser after add() when I tested to make sure it worked

Comment: THANKS BRAH....that was the only thing i needed....moving showuser after add thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var capnum = 0;
 function add()
 {
    capnum++;
     document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = capnum;
 }
 </script>

 <button id="display" name="subject" type="submit" value="<script> document.write(capnum) </script>" onclick="showUser(this.value);add()" >NEXT</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setAttribute` Property of `javascript`

```
<button name="subject" id="myId"  type="submit"  onclick="add(this.value);add()" >NEXT</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var capnum = 0;
function add()
{
capnum++;
 document.getElementById('myId').setAttribute('value', capnum);  
}

</script>
```